# Inequality for normed power n, m

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, linear-matrix-inequalities

Let $ B (H) $ indicate the set of all bounded linear operators on a complex separable Hilbert space $ H $.
Let $ A \in B(H) $, where $ A $ is a positive semi-definite operator in $ H $ (i.e. $ \langle Ax, x \rangle >0 $ for all $x \in H$)
Then $ \|A^n\|^m \leq \|A^m\|^n $, for all $ m>n>0$.

How can prove this inequality? Or any hint it.

Comment: @ToniMhax For self-adjoint operators it's actually equal, the LHS is $(\sup_{\lambda\in \sigma(A)}\lambda^n)^m$ and the RHS the same with $m$ and $n$ swapped.

Comment: Since $n >m$, you may have $A^m=0$ whereas $A^n \ne 0$, so the proposed inequality cannot be true in generality.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Look the operator is positive semi definite not equal zero.  Others thanks.

Comment: It is still false. Take $$A = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right).$$ Then it is definite positive, the operator norm of $A$ is strictly larger than $1$, but the operator norm of $$A^n = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & n \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right).$$ is equivalent to $n$ as $n$ goes to infinity.